# Read Dynamic Json

Tags: c#, json

I have a requirement to read the json in which keys are vary and store into dictionary in C#.net. I am using Newtonsoft json. I am deserializing like below.

```
var inputData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myObj)
```

If the keys are fixed I can do like below.

```
var val = inputData.Account;
```

But here keys are dynamic. Below is my json data.

```
 {
     "data": {
                "Account": "150.80",
                "Name": "XYZ",
                "Description": "Some Value"
             }
 }
```

Here name value pairs may change. i.e., It may have like below also.

```
 {
         "data": {
                    "Cost": "154.80",
                    "Type": "S1234",
                    "Period": "Some Value"
                 }
 }
```

How to access dynamic keys and store into a dictionary.

Comment: Use JSON.Net, it lets you deserialize the information into dynamic dictionaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer was for the previous posted question, not the newly revised question...  I'm leaving it in, since it probably has *some* useful details.**

I'd recommend using Json.NET to do this.

If the fact that the json data always has the field named `data`, then you can write fairly predictable code to output the contents of `data` into a dictionary.

Off the top of my head, I'd probably go for an anonymous type-based deserialization, kind of like this:

```
var json = @"{
 ""data"": {
            ""Account"": ""150.80"",
            ""Name"": ""XYZ"",
            ""Description"": ""Some Value""
           }
 }";

var schema = new { data = new Dictionary<string, object>()};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, schema);
```

You'd have to reach into `result.data` to get that dictionary.

You could also just use `JObject` to pull out the values from `data` directly, but probably would need to parse that data into a dictionary, so it'd be sort of a double call going on, like this:

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var data = jobj["data"];
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>
              (data.ToString());
```

There's probably more ways to do this even more efficiently. Like I said, these are just ideas off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks @code4life. Your answer is perfect and suits my requirement. But I do not know why others are not able to understand and down voted my question. I referred my question in the internet, as the answer is not available then I posted my question here